# CPLEX - Java How to create an absolute values summation constraint

Tags: java, cplex

I have to create a constraint like this:

```
z = Σi|xi - 1|
```

How can I do this in java with CPLEX?

x is an integer vector and z an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use functions IloCplex.eq(), IloCplex.abs(), IloCplex.sum() and IloCplex.diff(). The are all described in the [reference documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/cplex/IloCplex.html). You may also want to take a look at the Java examples that ship with CPLEX. They illustrate how to build and add constraints.